# Remove Image overlay on history.go(-1)

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I'm using a simple overlay when hovering a link. Javascript switches the `display:none` to activate this overlay. When i click on the link an go back via Browser button, the link is still in it's hover state.

Is there a simple way to reset to `display:none` when clicking the browsers back button?